# Silverlight 4: Dynamically add a HyperlinkButton to a stackpanel

Tags: silverlight

I would like to retrieve a list of links from SQLServer, and programmatically create some HyperlinkButtons from that list. These buttons should be added to a StackPnael. What is the best way to do this?

Something along the lines of:

```
    private void RefreshMenu()
    {
        var dc = new FrameworkCMSDomainContext();
        var query = dc.GetCMSPagesForSectionQuery(Section);

        dc.Load(query, (s) =>
        {
            foreach(var page in dc.CMSPages)
            {
                HyperlinkButton btn = new HyperlinkButton();
                btn.NavigateUri = new Uri("/" + Section + "/" + page.Name, UriKind.Relative);
                btn.Content = page.Name;
                btn.TargetName = "ContentFrame";
                //Add to stackpanel here
            }

        }, null);
    }

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">

    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="AddPage" Click="AddPage_Click">Add</Button>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinksStackPanel.Children.Add(btn);
```

Comment: Error 3 The name 'LinkStackPanel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Is the code you posted directly from the code behind of the UserControl that contains the XAML at the bottom?  The value in `x:Name` of your XAML is the name you can use to access the control from the code behind.  (Check that you spelled it correctly, your comment is missing as s)

Comment: That is true, i corrected it. But the error still persists. In fact I spelled it wrong because it was not in the intellisense popup list.

Comment: Is your `RefreshMenu()` method in the code behind of the UserControl?  That is the only place that LinksStackPanel will be recognized.

Comment: I notice that the generated file is not correct (VerticalMenu.g.i.cs) None of the controls are present.

Comment: I just had to create a new user control, and copy over the code. Strange why sometimes in VS2010 the auto-generated files will just quit on me.

Comment: The linked, auto-gen files sometimes have some strange issues.  Anytime you have weird issues like that you should be able to delete the file itself and it should regenerate it for you.