# How to find a particular stackpanel inside a listbox and add hyperlinkbuttons dynamically to that stackpanel?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to know how to find a particular stackpanel inside a listbox and want to add hyperlinkbuttons to that stackpanel(which is inside a listbox)dynamically from c# codebehind.?

Comment: use datacontxt to find the items inside a listbox. And changing the visibility of already added control is easier than adding a control from code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class to iterate over the item hierarchy inside the ListBox until you find the StackPanel with a matching name. Here is [an example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439518/using-visualtreehelper-on-listbox-cant-get-listboxitems), look in the accepted answer for the code snippet.

As for the adding items dynamically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893928/silverlight-4-dynamically-add-a-hyperlinkbutton-to-a-stackpanel) covers it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also find out like this

```
ListBoxItem selItem = (ListBoxItem)(listboxWeight.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listboxWeight.SelectedIndex));

StackPanel weightpanel = (StackPanel)selItem.Content;

var panel1 = weightpanel.Children[0] as HyperlinkButton;
```